# Get db row data from listview, populate an activity's widgets, then update row

Tags: android, sqlite, listview

I have a ListView that gets populated with db row data. I then open an intent which is identical to the original page used for the create/new row. I want to re-use this for editing/updating. I am trying to get the entire set of row data into the new edit avtivity so it can be manipulated and the row then updated. Note that there are no ListActivities used, and I don't plan on going that route. There's also a delete and cancel in the plan, but I'll be happy getting the update to work for now.

The insert class has:

```
        @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if(v==submitButton){
            String name = nameEditText.getText().toString();
            String location = locationEditText.getText().toString();
            String notes = notesEditText.getText().toString();

            long insert = db.insertRecord(name, location, retn, nh, busy, child, man, woman, notes);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Record inserted successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            db.close();
            finish();

        startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class));


        }else if(v==cancelButton){
            startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class));
             }else yada, yada, yada...
```

The class with the ListView:

```
    public class ViewRecords extends Activity implements OnItemLongClickListener, OnClickListener {
private static final String TAG = null;
int position;
Dialog updateDialog;
EditText updatename,updatelocation;
Button updateButton,cancelButton;
DBAdapter db;
Cursor c;
ListView list;
MyAdapter myAdapter;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.view);
    db = new DBAdapter(getApplicationContext());
    db.openDatabase();


    list = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);
     updateListView();

    list.setOnItemLongClickListener(new OnItemLongClickListener() {
          @Override
          public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> list, View customlistView,
            int position, long id) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
              "ListItem Number " + position + ". id: " + id, Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
              .show();                  
            Intent myIntent = new Intent(ViewRecords.this, Edit.class);
            ViewRecords.this.startActivity(myIntent);

            return true;
          }
        });           
}
class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter{         
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return c.getCount();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }
```

...and the edit class:

```
      public class Edit extends Activity{  // implements OnClickListener{
      EditText nameEditText,locationEditText, notesEditText;
      DBAdapter db;
      CheckBox cb1, cb2, cb3, cb4, cb5, cb6;
      @Override
      protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.insert);
```

So, can anyone suggest how I might get there from here?
Thanks!

EDIT: Adapter below.

```
        public class DBAdapter {
    // database name
        public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "UserDB";
    // table name
        public static final String TABLE_NAME = "tableone";
    // database version
        public static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    // defining columns
        public static final String COL_ROWID = "rowid";
        public static final String COL_NAME = "name";
        public static final String COL_LOCATION = "location";
        public static final String COL_RETURN = "retn";    
        public static final String COL_NH = "nh";
        public static final String COL_BUSY = "busy";
        public static final String COL_CHILD = "child";
        public static final String COL_MAN = "man";
        public static final String COL_WOMAN = "woman";
        public static final String COL_NOTES = "notes";

        String CREATE_TABLE = "create table tableone(rowid integer primary key autoincrement,name text,location text not null, retn text, nh text, busy text, child text, man text, woman text, notes text)";

        Context context;

        DBHelper dbHelper;
        SQLiteDatabase db; 
        public DBAdapter(Context c) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        this.context = c;
        dbHelper = new DBHelper(context);
        }

        DBAdapter openDatabase() {
            db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
            return this;

        }

        void close() {
            dbHelper.close();
        }

        long insertRecord(String name, String location, String retn, String nh, String busy, String child, String man, String woman, String notes) {
            ContentValues con = new ContentValues();
            con.put(COL_NAME, name);
            con.put(COL_LOCATION, location);
            con.put(COL_RETURN, retn);
            con.put(COL_NH, nh);
            con.put(COL_BUSY, busy);
            con.put(COL_CHILD, child);
            con.put(COL_MAN, man);
            con.put(COL_WOMAN, woman);
            con.put(COL_NOTES, notes);

            return db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, con);
        }

        Cursor getAllRecords(){
            String[] columns = {COL_ROWID,COL_NAME,COL_LOCATION, COL_RETURN, COL_NH, COL_BUSY, COL_CHILD, COL_MAN, COL_WOMAN, COL_NOTES};
            return db.query(TABLE_NAME, columns, null, null, null, null, null);
         }

        void deleteAllRecords(){
            db.delete(TABLE_NAME, null, null);
         }

        void deleteOneRecord(String rowid){
            db.delete(TABLE_NAME, rowid +"="+COL_ROWID, null);
         }

        long updateRecord(String rowid,String name,String location, String retn, String nh, String busy, String child, String man, String woman, String notes){
            ContentValues con = new ContentValues();
            con.put(COL_NAME, name);
            con.put(COL_LOCATION, location);
            con.put(COL_NH, nh);
            con.put(COL_RETURN, retn);
            con.put(COL_BUSY, busy);
            con.put(COL_CHILD, child);
            con.put(COL_MAN, man);
            con.put(COL_WOMAN, woman);
            con.put(COL_NOTES, notes);        

            return db.update(TABLE_NAME, con, rowid +"="+COL_ROWID, null);
         }

    class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
        public DBHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE);
        }

        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }
      }
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

instead of getting the entire data from the row a better solution would be to get the id of the row that was clicked then pass the id in the bundle in your intent to your activity then pull the id from the intent in your `Edit` activity and pull everything from the database on that row with that id.

You dont really show how you are using your adapter so I really cannot tell you much more but if you wanted to pass whole data you would either have to pass each values you want to send seperate;y in the intent or create an object that holds the data and have that class extend `Parcelable` and configure the class to work as a Parcelable object

Comment: Your thoughts on not getting the whole row make sense. I have tried to get the id for the row, but it always returns 0. I'll add relevant adapter info...Thx.

Comment: this: onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> list, View customlistView, int position, long id) gives me the correct list position, but not the row.

Comment: you should be using `SimpleCursorAdapter` for your adapter then you can just pass in a cursor from your database and inorder for the id to work your primary key needs to be `_id` in your database

Comment: If you want to use base adapter then you will need to create an object that holds all the data and pull it from the adapter when an item is clicked for example `MyObject obj = list.getItemAtPosition(position);`

Comment: But,  don't I need to use a ListActivity to do so?

Comment: what makes you think you do?